How to get a list of all SPL tokens and their token contract which have been traded on Raydium?
I would like to get a list of all Solana token contracts which have traded on Raydium. Once I have this list I expect to be able to retrieve all trade data for each token contract (x/Sol) through something like Alchemy.
